ReactJS - Redux , no consigo que funcione mi store
estoy creando un store con redux, aplicando el terminologia duck, que es unicamente hacer las acciones,constantes y mutaciones en el mismo fichero, por un tema de orden:
Tengo mi pokeDucks.js:
import axios from "axios";

//constantes
const dataInicial = {
    array:[]
}

const OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO = 'OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO';

//reducer
export default function pokeReducer(state = dataInicial,action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO:
            return {
                ...state,array:action.payload
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//acciones
export const obtenerPokemonesAccion = () => async (dispatch,getState) =>{

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=20')
        dispatch({
            type:OBTENER_POKEMONES_EXITO,
            payload:res.data.results
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error al llamar obtenerPokemonesAccion');
    }
}

Y mi store.js:
import { combineReducers, compose } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pokeReducer from "./pokeDucks";

//siempre se llama al reducer de los diferentes ficheroDucks.js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  pokemones: pokeReducer
});

//Para debugear redux en el explorador web: 
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

//Montamos el store que queremos devolver
const store = {
  reducer:rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>{

  }
}

export default store;

Y mi index.js, que es donde llamo al store que he creado:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

El tema es que me esta dando este error al cargar el navegador :
ERROR
store.getState is not a function
./node_modules/react-redux/dist/react-redux.mjs/Provider/previousState<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45304:51
mountMemo@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20779:23
useMemo@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21164:20
useMemo@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34914:25

Lo dejo tambien en imagen:


Veo que te estas olvidando de createStore.
import { combineReducers, compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pokeReducer from "./reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    pokemones: pokeReducer
});

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const customMiddleWare = store => next => action => {
    next(action);
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(customMiddleWare))

export default store;

Por otro lado, vas a observar que createStore esta despreciado. Veo que estas utilizando @reduxjs/toolkit pero estas utilizando funcionalidades de la libreria redux por lo que te invito a indagar acerca de:

createSlice (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice)
configureStore (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore)

Si quieres utilizar actions te invito a investigar acerca de:

createAsyncThunk (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)

